# Vegas Pro 13 : Project's and Timeline's framerate are suddenly not the same

Tags: video, framerate, vegas-pro

So here's the thing : I'm editing on Vegas Pro 13, 25fps according to my origninal files. I just imported some sound I "mixed" externally.
And now, my timeline acts in 24fps although **my project is still in 25fps**. I don't know if it has something to do with the files I imported but the ctrl Z option is dead now. I can't figure out what the problem is, it's the first time I see anything like that in Vegas. The timeline should act according to the project setting, right ?  As shown in the screenshots bellow, I can't control every frame.

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your footage is in 25 fps? If so, try and see if you can change the interpretation of the clip like in premiere. Other than that, a restart is the only thing I got left to propose.